# Toggle between set of checkboxes and uncheck the checked one when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox, frontend

i have three checkboxes on my page and i want just one to be selected. If user clicks on another checkbox i uncheck the current one and check the clicked one. The problem here is that when a user check a box he just can't uncheck it... he can move to another one but i want to give the user option to uncheck the checked one as well. Any ideas? Thanks.

```js
    const checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    checkBoxes.forEach((checkBox) => {
        checkBox.addEventListener('click', () => {
            checkBoxes.forEach((checkBox) => {
                checkBox.checked = false;
            });

            checkBox.checked = true;

        });

    });
```

```html
        <input type="checkbox" value="Option1">
        <input type="checkbox" value="Option2">
        <input type="checkbox" value="Option3">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over all the checkboxes and only uncheck the ones that are not the clicked checkbox. Let the checkbox that you clicked handle itself.

```js
const checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

function handleCheckboxClick(event) {
  checkBoxes.forEach((checkBox) => {
    if (event.target !== checkBox) {
      checkBox.checked = false;
    }
  });
}

checkBoxes.forEach((checkBox) => {
  checkBox.addEventListener('click', handleCheckboxClick);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="Option1">
<input type="checkbox" value="Option2">
<input type="checkbox" value="Option3">
```

Comment: Massive well done mate and BIG Thank you! I spent hours today on this.. :D